# How to aggregate different async sources into a Single using RxJava2?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java2

Let's say I have this synchronous method:

```
public FruitBowl getFruitBowl() {
    Apple apple = getApple(); // IO intensive
    Banana banana = getBanana(); // CPU intensive
    return new FruitBowl(apple, banana);
}
```

I can use the Java concurrency API to turn it into an async method, which would turn out somewhat like this:

```
public Future<FruitBowl> getFruitBowl() {
    Future<Apple> appleFuture = getAppleAsync(); // IO intensive
    Future<Banana> bananaFuture = getBananaAsync(); // CPU intensive
    return createFruitBowlAsync(appleFuture, bananaFuture); // Awaits appleFuture and bananaFuture and then returns a new FruitBowl
}
```

What is the idiomatic Rx way of doing this while taking advantage of it's schedulers (io and computation) and return a Single?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip` operator. And for each of the async operation define a different thread. If you don't do so, the methods will be executed one after the other, on the same thread.

I would create an `Observable` version of both methods, in order to return respectively `Observable<Apple>` and `Observable<Banana>` and use them in this way:

```
Observalbe.zip(getAppleObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()), 
               getBananaObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
     (apple, banana) -> new FruitBowl(apple, banana)))
     .subscribe(/* do your work here with FruitBowl object */);
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@Joseph82/concurrent-tasks-with-zip-operator-99773466039f) more details about how to parallelize operations with `zip` operator

Comment: Some really important gotchas in that article!